# How to use (find)where in backbone to get a specific field of an array

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I use to use the `where` method from the `Collections` in backbone. But I don't see how to fetch this result:

```
MyCollection.Group[x].id
```

As you can guess, `MyCollection` is the collection, `Group` is an array, and `id` is the field I would like to match for a specific value, something like:

```
MyCollection.findWhere(Group[x].id: 34);
```

I have seen the "contains" function of `underscore` but it doesn't seems to work with associative arrays

Is there a way to do it or should we parse the collection manually using Javascript ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Collection.where](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) and [Collection.findWhere](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere) are convenience functions for simple filters. In your case, you would use the more complex `Collection.find` (proxied to [_.find](http://underscorejs.org/#find))

> **find** _.find(list, iterator, [context])
>   Looks through each value in the list, returning the first one that passes a truth test
>   (iterator). The function returns as soon as it finds an acceptable
>   element, and doesn't traverse the entire list.

And if I understand correctly your condition, it could look like

```
MyCollection.find(function(model) {
    return _.findWhere(model.get('Group'), {id: 34});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can choose to use jQuery .find() . see examples here: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Are you sure it's not only for the DOM ? I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined` trying to call `$(MyCollection).find({ Group: { id: 34 }});`

Comment: jQuery's `.find()` is only for the DOM. `$.grep()` would be the jQuery's correct answer.